# Visio, Copy shape data to other objects

Tags: ms-office, visio, shapes

I have just defined shape data for a single object within MS Visio (2010), Now i would like to apply the new shape data to a few other relevant objects on the page (these shapes are created with no existing shape data)

What is the best way to assign this new shape data?

the only thing i can come up with at the moment, is to link Visio to an Excel datasoure and drag the datasource items onto each existing shape, i know that will assign shape data to each element, but will also change the current name text.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "shape data sets"

1. Open shape-data window.
2. Right-click, select "Shape data sets" => new window "shape data sets" will be opened.
3. Select source shape, in the "shape data sets" click "Add set", name it somehow (e.g. "my dataset").
4. Set checkbox on "my dataset", select target shapes, click "apply set".

That's it basically.. Check out Visio docs: http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/visio-help/add-data-to-shapes-HP001231008.aspx

Comment: Oh wow. yes I remember this functionality from a while back... Funny how easily you forget these things. Thanks!